# Create 2D image using DWT detail coefficients?

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing, visualization, wavelet-transform

I want to create 2D image using DWT detail coefficients as the figure below. How do I do this using python?

[image: DWT detail cofficients(level 1 to 5)]

```py
def wavelet(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,1))
    ax.set_title("interictal data: ")
    ax.plot(data)
    plt.show()
    waveletname = 'sym5'
    fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=2, figsize=(6,6))
    for ii in range(5):
        (data, coeff_d) = pywt.dwt(data, waveletname)
        axarr[ii, 0].plot(data, 'r')
        axarr[ii, 1].plot(coeff_d, 'g')
        axarr[ii, 0].set_ylabel("Level {}".format(ii + 1), fontsize=14, rotation=90)
        axarr[ii, 0].set_yticklabels([])
        if ii == 0:
            axarr[ii, 0].set_title("Approximation coefficients", fontsize=14)
            axarr[ii, 1].set_title("Detail coefficients", fontsize=14)
        axarr[ii, 1].set_yticklabels([])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    A=[[cD1],[cD2],[cD3],[cD4],[cD5]]
    # Plot histogram of A
    plt.hist(A)
    # Show histogram
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to start . I am a beginner in Python , I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work
`A=[[cD1],[cD2],[cD3],[cD4],[cD5]]
    # Plot histogram of A
    plt.hist(A)
    # Show histogram
    plt.show()`